# Rewrite rules not working with .htaccess but do with vhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I am a little miffed by this one, the rules I am pretty sure are correct yet when using them in a `.htaccess` file they just won't apply.

The rules push everything through a dispatch.php which then handles my MVC views and controllers for me.

```
 //htaccess file - Accessing http://topaz.local/app/users/login
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dispatch/.php$
RewriteCond /var/www/topaz%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /dispatch.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^x/.!dispatch/.php([^b]+)!dispatch/.php$ !dispatch/.php [L,NE]
```

```
[topaz.local/sid#12a94f8][rid#1ee71b0/initial] [perdir C:/var/www/topaz/] add path info postfix: C:/var/www/topaz/app/users -> C:/var/www/topaz/app/users/login
[topaz.local/sid#12a94f8][rid#1ee71b0/initial] [perdir C:/var/www/topaz/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/var/www/topaz/app/users/login -> app/users/login
[topaz.local/sid#12a94f8][rid#1ee71b0/initial] [perdir C:/var/www/topaz/] applying pattern '^(/.*)$' to uri 'app/users/login'
[topaz.local/sid#12a94f8][rid#1ee71b0/initial] [perdir C:/var/www/topaz/] add path info postfix: C:/var/www/topaz/app/users -> C:/var/www/topaz/app/users/login
[topaz.local/sid#12a94f8][rid#1ee71b0/initial] [perdir C:/var/www/topaz/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/var/www/topaz/app/users/login -> app/users/login
[topaz.local/sid#12a94f8][rid#1ee71b0/initial] [perdir C:/var/www/topaz/] applying pattern '^x/.!dispatch/.php([^b]+)!dispatch/.php$' to uri 'app/users/login'
[topaz.local/sid#12a94f8][rid#1ee71b0/initial] [perdir C:/var/www/topaz/] pass through C:/var/www/topaz/app/users
```

Compared to the output via the vhost:

```
[topaz.local/sid#18374e8][rid#1868310/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /app/users/login
[topaz.local/sid#18374e8][rid#1868310/initial] applying pattern '^(/.*)$' to uri '/app/users/login'
[topaz.local/sid#18374e8][rid#1868310/initial] rewrite '/app/users/login' -> '/dispatch.php?url=/app/users/login'
[topaz.local/sid#18374e8][rid#1868310/initial] split uri=/dispatch.php?url=/app/users/login -> uri=/dispatch.php, args=url=/app/users/login
[topaz.local/sid#18374e8][rid#1868310/initial] local path result: /dispatch.php
[topaz.local/sid#18374e8][rid#1868310/initial] prefixed with document_root to C:/var/www/topaz/dispatch.php
[topaz.local/sid#18374e8][rid#1868310/initial] go-ahead with C:/var/www/topaz/dispatch.php [OK]
```

Comment: Why do you have `!` all over the place here: `RewriteRule ^x/.!dispatch/.php([^b]+)!dispatch/.php$ !dispatch/.php [L,NE]`?

Comment: Try removing the `/var/www/topaz` from your condition